# Parse vs Urban Airship

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, urbanairship.com

This is as simple as it sounds. I know there is a lot of documentation, but nothing beats experience, and sharing it in a few lines is better than reading a ton of complex documents for hours.

So, if anyone has already used both (or at least feels he is reliable in explaining his point),  i would appreciate some feedback about the pros and cons of both Parse and Urban Airship for Push Notifications.

Even though i've already found some of these answers by myself, I think the most important points to keep in mind are :

- Pricing
- Quality
- Speed
- Documentation
- Usability (hard to maintain/implement, etc.)
- Information (stats about notifications, where/when/number, etc.)
- Anything that i might not think about.

I'm all ears ;)

Comment: 100% opinion based...

Comment: Not specifically. You can compare price, facts, etc. And even then, opinions arent a bad thing.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ "Thus, questions that are not answerable — discussions, debates, opinions — should be closed as subjective"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit late but I would recommend **Parse** over Urban Airship. I've used both in limited quantities.

One of the biggest differences is price. Urban Airship is 14 times more expensive as reference here http://killerapi.blogspot.sg/2013/01/warning-urban-airship-pricing-is-much.html.

Both have great quality and speed.

My favorite thing about Parse is their documentation is top notch. Seriously, check it out. It is awesome. They also provide a lot of other features like cloud code outside of pushes if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, i went for Parse at the time of asking, for the EXACT reasons  you named :)